# Give a proper $\mathbb{P}$ for the following experiment.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

> We roll a $n$ sided die, twice, and want to note down the probability that the value of the first roll is strictly higher than the value of the second roll. Give a proper $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{P}$.

For $\Omega$ I have: $\Omega := \{(i,j) : i,j \in \{1,...,n\}\}$. However, I do not know how to get $\mathbb{P}$. Of course I could make a table, look for a pattern and try to find a solution that way, but is there a more "mathematical" approach?

Comment: The sample space, $\Omega,$ includes all results, not just the results where $i>j.$ otherwise, you can’t use the space to calculate this probability

Comment: Ah, so I have to remove the condition that the first roll is strictly greater than the second roll, correct?

Comment: Yes, the probably of your event happening is an answer to “what proportion of all possible results ($\Omega$) satisfies our conditi9n?”

Answer (score 0):

Your $\Omega:=[n]^2$ is correct, and the assumptions about such dies imply that all $n^2$ elements of $\Omega$ have the same probability ${1\over n^2}$.

Since the elements of $\Omega$ are pairs $(i,j)\in[n]^2$ you have to count how many such pairs $(i,j)$ satisfy $i>j$. This counting amounts to a sum of the form $1+2+3+\ldots\ $.

I think this is "mathematical" enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put into symbols what others have said in words, in general you can write, for any subset $A$ of a finite sample space $\Omega,$
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(A)= {\sum_{\omega\in A}1\over \sum_{\omega\in\Omega}1}\end{align}$$
assuming the outcomes in $\Omega$ are equally likely. So, if the sample space is $\Omega=[n]^2$ and $A=\{(x,y)\in \Omega:\ x > y\},$ then

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(A)&= {\sum_{(x,y)\in A}1\over \sum_{(x,y)\in\Omega}1}\\[2ex]
&= {\sum_{x\in[n]}\sum_{y\in[n]}\mathbb{1}_{x>y}\over \sum_{x\in[n]}\sum_{y\in[n]}{1}}\\[2ex]
&= {\sum_{x\in[n]}(x-1)\over \sum_{x\in[n]}n}\\[2ex]
&= {(n-1)\cdot n/2\over n\cdot n}\\[2ex]
&={n-1\over 2n}
\end{align}$$